# Check if multiple parameters are not "" with a loop JS or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create a function which can take n1, n2, n... , n = number of params. 
I'm aware that there is such thing as using `arguments[0]` object to select parameters. Would it be possible to loop through all passed parameters and check that their value `! = ""`

```
function test () {
    loop through arguments[] object 
    IF arguments[index] == "" return false 
};
```

`test("ok","", "no");` would return false

`test("ok");` would return true

The objective is that the function works even if there isn't a set amount of parameters.

Javascript and jQuery answers both welcome.

PS: If it is possible, are there limitations ? Possible problems.

Answer (score 3):

Short  *ECMAScript5* solution using `Array.prototype.slice()` and [***Array.prototype.some()***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) functions:

```js
function checkFilling() {
  return !Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments).some(function (arg) {
      return arg === "";
  });
}
    
console.log(checkFilling("ok","", "no"));
console.log(checkFilling("ok"));
```

---

Alternative *ECMAScript6* approach using [***Array.from()***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) function(to create a new array from an array-like `arguments` object):

```js
function checkFilling() {
    return !Array.from(arguments).some(arg => arg === "");
}

console.log(checkFilling("ok","", "no"));
console.log(checkFilling("ok"));
```

Comment: Some needs polyfill < ie9

Comment: Further to mplungjan's comment, you'd be better served, I think, showing one ES6 approach, using both [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) and `Array.prototype.some()`) and a second approach using a fully ES5-compatible alternative (either with shims, polyfills or a pure ES5 approach).

Comment: @DavidThomas, added alternative ES6 approach

Comment: Thanks, but you left the `Array.some()` solution in your ES5-compatible answer; while this is legitimate for supporting browsers (which does *not* include IE<9) it does alienate such browsers as IE<9, my suggestion was really to adjust that approach to cater to *old* (archaic...) browsers and post the other, ES6 solution, for up-to-date browsers. :)

Answer (score 0):

Answering the question in the spirit it was asked with code that works in all browsers and is readable and understandable by beginners too

```js
function test() {
  for (var i=0,n=arguments.length;i<n; i++) {
    // return false if any argument is strictly equal to the empty string
    if (arguments[i]==="") return false; 
  }  
  return true;
}

// Tests

console.log(test(""),false)
console.log(test("1"),true)
console.log(test(1),true)
console.log(test("1",""),false)
console.log(test("1","2"),true)
```

Comment: Okay, I see you have a wall of sub-optimized code. Can you add some explanation?

Comment: You mean my pragmatic self-explanatory code that is understandable by noobs and runs on all browsers?

Comment: That doesn't explain... But good luck eith the code-wall. Also, store the length on a local variable. It's faster to access a local variable than to read a property from an object.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel What are you on about "wall" it is 2 lines of code, and storing the length is valid for large arrays so I have modified my code, but for small arrays like arguments are likely to be, it is not mandatory.

Comment: Why the null check?

Comment: To make sure it is not falsy

Comment: That is unecessary. Since you check if the value is an empty string (with `===`) , you don't need to check for null. `null === ""` returns false. You skip a check and speed up a tiny bit. If you used `==` you would need the null check.

Comment: Ok ok - I added null when I started writing and left it as a safeguard- it did no harm. Anyway, gone now